# Finding the interaction terms in Logistic Regression with 4 ind. variables (11 different ways of choosing int. terms)

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, interaction

When doing logistic regression with 4 independent variables, it is believed there will be significant interaction effects, and the strongest interaction will probably be when 3 or 4 of the variables are non-zero.  There will also be interactions with pairs of the variables being non-zero.

The 4 independent variables can have values from 0 to 6 (integers). This represents the count of a condition.  (A different condition is counted for each variable.

There are 11 different ways to choose one or more interactions terms here.

R throws an error with this command, as there are too many interactions:  (that's how I interpreted it when I wrote this - I don't recall the exact message now)

```
model_1 <- glm(as.factor(Success) ~ Var1*Var2*Var3*Var4, data = Dataset2, family="binomial")
```

How should I proceed in finding the significant interactions?

**UPDATE**

This problem has disappeared.

I reloaded the project and dataset in a new R-Studio session (the old one was closed), and re-ran the exact same command, and I am no longer getting an error.

```
model_1 <- glm(as.factor(Success) ~ Var1*Var2*var3*var4, data = Dataset2, family="binomial")
```

The model includes all 11 possible interaction terms.

**I guess the error was caused by some library conflict.**  If I had time, I'd go back through the history (long), reloading libraries to try and recreate the error message. I don't recall what the error message was now.

Comment: What do the 0-6 represent? The numbers 0-6? Seven categories? An ordinal scale like “very very low, very low, low, medium, extra medium, high, very high”?

Comment: There are only $4\times 3/2= 6$ pairwise interaction terms, and at most $2^4-4-1=11$ of all orders, not $11!=39916800$ of them!  Since `R` is throwing an error, something else is going on, but without knowing exactly what the circumstances are and what the error message says, there's little we can do.

Comment: @Dave  The values of 0 to 6 are a count (total).

Comment: I meant 4!.  I'm not sure now why I wrote 11!.  I guess it was a mental glitch.

Comment: Then that's just 24 combinations. The problem seems tractable.

Comment: I reloaded that dataset in a new R session.  I am no longer getting an error, running the exact same modeling command as before (a x b x c x d).  Eleven interaction terms are generated, and I can see that is full coverage.  There is no longer a problem.  If I had time, I'd go back through the history, loading the libraries as before, and try to recreate the problem.  I guess it was caused by some library conflict, but I don't recall now what error I was getting.  I interpreted it as an overflow, due to too many interaction terms. I'm updating the post with the glm() call and this status.

Comment: Now I wonder what you mean by "significant". The R output gives p-values.

Comment: Yes, and now I have those p-values, and now and can proceed with that project (when I'm done with the one I'm now working on.)

Comment: Anyway, thanks for finally posting something here, as now I know I can proceed with that project (I had shelved it)- which may end up being an important result.